# Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11821 "Cannot Decode" { NSLocalizedFailureReason=The media data could not be decoded. It may be damaged.}

Tags: iphone, xcode6, ios8.1

I have developed my application to merge multiple videos, it works fine in iOS 7 but somehow it stops working in iOS 8 and it gives me an erroe while exporting video with AVVideoCompositon.  Has anyone have any idea? I have also download the sample code of apple "AVSimpleEditor" and it also gives me an same error while exporting video.

Comment: dont worry it will work in device.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is the issue with the simulator of iOS 8. I was also facing the similar problem.

Dont worry, it will work fine in device.

Have a happy coding.....

Comment: Getting Same issue in device, Any Help?